# How do I create a Grid like Excel on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

In my project, inside a view I want to create a grid (gridview) as excel grid. What tools can I use?

Comment: Be more specific. It's not clear what is being asked here. "grid (gridview) as excel grid" -- what does that mean?

Comment: simply grid...I want create a grid

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grid view in iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265293/grid-view-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: See also [Data grids for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030335/data-grids-for-ios), [How can I create an interface similar to an Excel spreadsheet on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661148/how-can-i-create-an-interface-similar-to-an-excel-spreadsheet-on-the-iphone), and [How do you display a spreadsheet-like table in an iPhone view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714349/how-do-you-display-a-spreadsheet-like-table-in-an-iphone-view).

Answer (score 2):

NSMatrix and NSCollectionView are not available on iOS.
Have a look at AQGridView: https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView

(If you're attempting to build something as complex as a spreadsheet, though, you might eventually find that you need to build something custom.)

Comment: @blackguardian: What is what?

Comment: The application in the link is not what I search

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to take a look at NSMatrix or possibly NSCollectionView depending on what you want to store in your table cells. NSMatrix would be the direct analog to the Excel grid.

Comment: Can I use NSMatrix for Ios? , my project is for Ipad...

Comment: @blackguardian:any updates regarding your projects if so plz lemme know.right now i need to create a spreadsheet with some static data how to get the things done regarding the ui also am unable to progress.